# What is the difference between 何 and どれ?

Tags: grammar, interrogatives

何 means what and can be conjugated with か to mean something (何か要る : I need something) with も to mean everything/nothing (何も知らない : know nothing) and with でも to mean anything ( 何でもいい : anything is fine). Now what if I conjugate どれ(means which) in the same way as 何 with か も でも to mean one from a lot of choices, all/none of the choices, one but any of the choices. Actually I'm confused with the real definition of those. So what is the exact meaning of どれか,どれも,どれでも specifically and with examples please. The か there is not asking "which one?"

Comment: what is the difference between what and which ?

Comment: Pretty sure the difference between 何 and どれ is different from the difference between *what* and *which*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user17907's answer gives great examples, so I briefly show you the meanings of each phrase:

**どれか**: one/some of the choices (with no preference) ex:

> あなたは本をたくさん持っていますね。どれか貸してください。
>
> You have a number of books. Would you lend me one of them?

**どれも**: each of stuffs. everything.

> この店の果物はどれも新鮮だ。
>
> All the fruits they sell are fresh.

**どれでも**: all of the choices.

> 本を貸して。どれでもいいよ。
>
> Please lend me one of your books. Anything will do.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Japanese. I try to help you.
(My English is not good,so i explain briefly.)

何 is used when choices aren't shown.

どれ is used when choices are shown.

But,何 can be used when choices are shown.

(1)何

English

> A:I will go shopping. Do you need anything?
>
> B:Then,buy some apples for me.

Japanese

> A:買い物に行ってくるね。何か要る？
>
> B:じゃあリンゴを買ってきて。

(2)どれ

English

> A:I'm back. I bought various things.
>
> B:What did you buy?
>
> (A show B what A bought.)
>
> A:Apples,Bananas,strawberries and grapes. Do you want anything?
>
> B:Then,an apple please.

Japanese

> A:ただいま。 色々なものを買ってきたよ。
>
> B：何を買ったの？
>
> （AはBに買ったものを見せる）
>
> A:リンゴとバナナとイチゴとブドウだよ。どれかいる？
>
> B:じゃあリンゴをもらおうかな。